# Email to Case with outbound Message

Tags: apex-email-service, email2case

Is it possible to capture the `Email-to-Case` and create some outbound email using `Message.SingleEmailMessage`? Instead of using `Email Services` I have to use `Email-to-Case`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, as emails that come into Email-to-Case are captured in the [EmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) object and can be tagged into with Process Builder. Depending on your needs, you could write an invokable method or flow plugin that could accept inbound parameters pulled from the Email Message and do whatever you want.

So in your example, you could create a process that fires on Email Message and pass some stuff to an Autolaunched Flow that sent an email, or write a class with an Invokable Method that sends a SingleEmailMessage or does whatever else you want with the data from the Email Message.

Answer (score 0):

Other alternatives to @cricketlang :

**One** - is to have your mail system forward the inbound E2C emails *additionally* to some second email address (think of it as a bcc forward) and then pick up the emails via an Inbound Email Service handler

**Two** - Use a trigger on `EmailMessage`